# Microsoft Access SQL hw issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

Find the PC models with the maximum speed. Output a table consisting of five columns: (model, maker, speed, ram, price).

What I've come up with and only receive an error:

```
SELECT model,maker,speed,ram,price 
FROM (
SELECT MAX(PC.speed) AS speed , Product.maker
FROM Product INNER JOIN Pc ON Product.model = pc.model
GROUP BY Product.maker
```

Comment: That helped, but it keeps asking me to enter values for model, ram and price. Not sure how to fix this

Comment: *"it keeps asking me to enter values"* - What do you mean? If this is a different issue than please accept my answer below as correct and post a new question.

Comment: @KobyDouek You could've noticed that you're creating a query of a subquery, and that the main query has columns that the subquery doesn't have. Anyway, if you think the only problem is a missing bracket, the correct response is to post a comment and close the question as simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket `)`:

```
SELECT model,maker,speed,ram,price 
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(PC.speed) AS speed , Product.maker
    FROM Product INNER JOIN Pc ON Product.model = pc.model
    GROUP BY Product.maker
)
```